# Как добавить еще таблицы в SQL PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

У меня есть 4 таблицы (iphones,mac,ipad,watch). Как можно их объединить в данном коде?

```html
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM iphones WHERE name LIKE '%$searchkey%' ORDER BY rand()");
```

Вот сама структура БД - store 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно в этот код:

```html
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM iphones WHERE name LIKE '%$searchkey%' ORDER BY rand()");
```

Добавить каким-то образом еще 3 таблицы. (iphones,mac,ipad,watch)

Comment: Что означает "объединить" ? Какой результат вы хотите получить ? И ответ на подобные вопросы в любом случае не возможен если не известная полная структура таблиц и их связей

Comment: Изначально надо делать __одну единственную__ таблицу под товары или что там у вас. Тогда у вас не будет возникать вопросов как объединить.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `iphones`, `mac`, `ipad`, `watch` WHERE `iphones`.`name` LIKE '%$searchkey%' OR `mac`.`name` LIKE '%$searchkey%' OR `ipad`.`name` LIKE '%$searchkey%' OR `watch`.`name` LIKE '%$searchkey%' ORDER BY rand()");
```